# why the return value of function socket or accept can be used as the subscript for array in redis

Tags: sockets, redis

I read redis source below:

```
int aeCreateFileEvent(aeEventLoop *eventLoop, int fd, int mask,
        aeFileProc *proc, void *clientData)
{
    if (fd >= eventLoop->setsize) {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return AE_ERR;
    }
    aeFileEvent *fe = &eventLoop->events[fd];
    //...
}
```

The 'fd' argument is the return value of function socket or accept and used as the subscript for array 'eventLoop->events'. The 'eventLoop->setsize' is intialized to 10000+1024=11024.

So my question is: what are the range for return value of function socket or accept? why they can be used as subscript for array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to POSIX, a file descriptor is:

"A per-process unique, non-negative integer used to identify an open file for the purpose of file access. The value of a newly-created file descriptor is from zero to {OPEN_MAX}-1. A file descriptor can have a value greater than or equal to {OPEN_MAX} if the value of {OPEN_MAX} has decreased (see sysconf) since the file descriptor was opened. File descriptors may also be used to implement message catalog descriptors and directory streams."

Now, in practice, each Unix/Linux process has a kernel-resident file descriptor table whose index is precisely the file descriptor. The consequence is file descriptors cannot be very large integers, since the OS will try hard avoiding increasing the highest bound of the file descriptor table. Using a file descriptor indexed array in a user space application like Redis is therefore safe.

Furthermore, the POSIX standard guarantees that when a new file descriptor has to be provided, the lowest numbered unused file descriptor is systematically chosen. See for instance the POSIX specification of the [open call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) return value.

The consequence is the highest file descriptor of your process (i.e. file descriptor table highest bound) is always lower or equal to the peak number of file descriptors used by your process.

Comment: In redis , the 'eventLoop->setsize' value is initialized to REDIS_MAX_CLIENTS + 1024, where REDIS_MAX_CLIENTS is a macro equal to 10000, and 'eventLoop->setsize' can be changed by user config. As you explained, I think the best and safest way to do that is to define the array with the OPEN_MAX extentsion, but not anther macro. BTW, OPEN_MAX is deprecated.

Comment: No, do not bother with OPEN_MAX or any other macro. Just set this value to the max number of connections your Redis instance can expect.

Answer (score 0):

> what are the range for return value of function socket or accept?

In Unix/Linux a file descriptor `fd` or socket descriptor is a 'small integer'.

> why they can be used as subscript for array?

Because they are small integers.